# integration of rational function using indefinite integral

Tags: integration, proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

let us suppose that we are asked to integrate following rational function

Integral

$\int \frac{1} {(x-4)^2-15} dx$

for integrate  this  function, let us denote $u=x-4$, from where  we will get

$du=dx$

so original function will be same as
 $\int \frac{1} {u^2-15} du$

now  we can write

$ \frac{1} {u^2-15}=\frac {A}{u-\sqrt{15}}+\frac {B}{u+\sqrt{15}} $

from where we will get

$ \frac{1} {u^2-15}=\frac {0.5}{u-\sqrt{15}}-\frac {0.5}{u+\sqrt{15}} $

so that integral from each part will be

$ 0.5*log(u-\sqrt{15})-0.5*log(u+\sqrt{15})$

after inserting of  $u=x-4$  we  will get

$ 0.5*log(x-4-\sqrt{15})-0.5*log(x+\sqrt{15}-4)+C$

i think everything is correct right? am i missing anything ?

EDDIT :

aaaa  i  get point   what i am missing,  there must be $\sqrt{15}$ in denominator, so  that 
$ \frac{0.5}{\sqrt{15}}*log(x-4-\sqrt{15})-
\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{15}}*log(x+\sqrt{15}-4)+C$

because  after  equality of

$ \frac{1} {u^2-15}=\frac {A}{u-\sqrt{15}}+\frac {B}{u+\sqrt{15}} $

we will get

$u*(A+B)=0  $

and from second   equality

$\sqrt{15}*(A-B)=1$

from where

$A-B=\frac{1} {\sqrt{15}}$

Comment: Without looking: You're missing $+C$ at the end.

Comment: yes  it is  of course, but i  was missing something else

Comment: and also, $\int 1/x=\ln|x|+C$

Comment: @Arnaldo  see equality, i need  it